# How to share code between content script and addon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing an extension for Firefox 4+.

I have some code in a file named `utils.js` which I'd like to call from both the addon's `main.js` and from the `page-mod`'s content script.

Is it possible to refer from both to the same `utils.js`? If so, how?

Edit: Even better would be a solution allowing me to use the same code in a Google Chrome extension, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this same problem. You'd think there'd be an obvious solution. Here's what I've been doing for firefox (haven't worked with chrome):

I have a file lib/dbg.js containing my basic debug functions that I want to use everywhere.

In each content scriptable module in my main.js, I have this:

```
contextMenu.Item({
...
contentScript: export_internals(require('dbg')),
contentScriptFile: my-actual-scripts.js
...
```

and then in main I have a function

```
function export_internals(module) {
    var code = '';
    for (name in module) {
        var val = module[name];
        if (val.constructor === String)
            code += name + ' = "' + val + '";';
        else
            code += val;
    }
    return code;
}
```

which basically just cycles through the exported properties (variables, functions, etc) and makes use of things like Function.toString() to basically build a stringified version of the dbg module and pass it as an inline content script. This function probably isn't hugely general as I just wrote it to handle simple functions and strings (the only two data types I needed) but the principle should be easily applied even if you were to just do something like

```
contentScript: require('dbg').my_function.toString()
```

It's clearly a bit of a hack but a pretty reliable one so far. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to

1. put all the "logic" (and my "utils" module) in the addon code
2. keep the content script as simple as possible
3. and whenever content script needs information that would require the utils module I use the asynchronous communication system between content script (self.port.emit, self.on...) and addon code (worker.port.on...)

The solution has lead to a better design of my addon. But I don't know if the async approach would work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find an existing solution I'm now just copying the same file to multiple directories (as part of the build/debug process).

This seems to work best for now especially since most part of the source code is reused in a Google Chrome implementation of the extension, too.

To make `utils.js` usable in Firefox content scripts and in Chrome (both have no CommonJS) I'm  importing it like this:

```
var Utils = Utils || require('utils').Utils;
```

The relevant parts of `utils.js` look like this:

```
function initUtils() {
    var result = {
        // ..define exported object...
    };
    return result;
};

// Chrome
var Utils = initUtils();
var exports = exports || {}; 
// Firefox
exports.Utils = Utils;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer to [Implementing Reusable Modules](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/implementing-reusable-module.html) at Mozilla's add-on SDK reference site.  I'm still not quite clear on how to do the `exports` invocation.  In their example they use the same name for the function and the file.  So, in the line `exports.translate = translate;` does the `translate` on the left refer to the function `translate()` while the one on the right refers to the file `translate.js`, or maybe *vice versa*?

magnoz' reply above (in which the function name and file name differ due to caSE sENSITiVitY) seems to suggest I should just use the function name twice and ignore the file name.  Is this the case?

Comment: Maybe https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/reusable-modules.html is an equivalent document. Maybe it isn't.